# Statics of a rigid solid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, momentum

I need help with this problem...[image]

I need to calculate the angle so that this whole thing is in equilibrium. 
I don't have any problem with the conservation of the force. But when I get to the conservation of the sum of the momentum force, I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For the mechanical equilibrium of any rigid body, you must ensure 2 things:

1. Net force on the system = 0 $\Rightarrow \sum \vec F=0$ and
2. Net torque on the system = 0 $\Rightarrow \sum \vec \tau=0$

Solve these 2 equations to find the value of $\theta$.